# Drop table name same as Database name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Currently by mistake I created a table with the same name as a Database name in SQL server. Now I want to drop the table. How should I do that?

- table name: `dbo.employee`
- database name: `dbo`

Comment: So what is the problem to drop it?

Comment: What's the issue? T-SQL uses different commands for different object types, so there's no ambiguity here.

Comment: looks like schema name and database name is same rather then table name and db name. But still there should not be any problem.

Comment: `IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.employee', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.employee`

Comment: Actually i am trying to rename it but its not working "sp_rename 'dbo.employee','employee'". so i try to delete it that too not working. table not found error.

Comment: It looks like i don't have permission to drop is there any way to rename it?

Comment: dbo is schema name right.?

Answer (score 2):

Let your table name be same as DB name; that won't cause any issue cause to drop a table you use `drop table ...` command and to drop database `drop database ...` command. BTW, from your post that `dbo` rather looks like schema name.